# Convert array of objects into array by field with Underscore.js or jQuery - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

Is there a way to convert an array like this:

```
"team" : [   {       "player" : "John",   "rank" : 0 }, {       "player" : "Peter",   "rank" : 2 } ]
```

to this:

```
"team" : [ "John", "Peter" ]
```

with Underscore.js or jQuery?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck):

> A convenient version of what is perhaps the most common use-case for
>   map: extracting a list of property values.

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
_.pluck(stooges, 'name');
=> ["moe", "larry", "curly"]
```

Comment: Excelent answer... +1

Comment: Use _.map instead of _.pluck. In the latest version of lodash _.pluck has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with plain old javascript via the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function

```
var someArray = [
    {name:'John', age:23},
    {name:'Foo', age:34},
    {name:'Bar', age:10},
    {name:'Doe', age:65}
];
var nameArray = someArray.map(function(el) {return el.name;});
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure JavaScript
Just iterate through it and push the player into a new array:

```
var array = [];
for(i in team){
  array.push(team[i].player);
}
```

or with underscore.js use [plug](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck)

```
var array = _.pluck(team, 'player');
```